# Read a file and sort it alphabetically by certain rules

Tags: c#, sorting, streamreader, streamwriter

I need to read a list of names from a text file `nameInput.txt`, the names are formatted as `first_name,last_name`, one pair per line.

For example:

```
David,Smith
Russell,Jones
Andrew,Jones
```

Then I need to arrange it in alphabetical order by with primary key last name, secondary key first name, for example:

```
Jones Andrew
Jones Russell
Smith David
```

Last, I need to write the sorted data to another file `nameOutput.txt`, the names are written as one pair per row in `last_name first_name` order, for example:

```
Jones Andrew
Jones Russell
Smith David
```

This is my code currently:

```
    class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        List<string> list = new List<string> ();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Documents/inputName.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                list.Add (line);
                Console.WriteLine (line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to either post what you have tried or start learning C#.

Comment: I can currently read the names from the file by using streamreader. I just do not know how to reverse the first and last names. Once I do that, I can then use list.Sort() to put it in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use `LINQ` methods, here is an example about how to do it:

```
 var lines = File.ReadLines("inputFilePath")
            .Select(x => x.Split(',').Reverse().ToArray())
            .OrderBy(x => x[0])
            .ThenBy(x => x[1])
            .Select(x => string.Join(" ", x));

File.WriteAllLines("outputFilePath", lines);
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a non-linq solution with your code:

Create a custom comparer:

```
public class NameComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return 0;

        if (x == null || y == null) return -1; 

        var parts1 = x.Split();
        var parts2 = y.Split();

        if (parts1.Length > 1 && parts2.Length > 1)
        {
            if (parts1[0] != parts2[0]) return parts1[0].CompareTo(parts2[0]);

            return parts1[1].CompareTo(parts2[1]);
        }

        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

And use it to sort your names:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Documents/inputName.txt"))
{
      string line;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
           var parts = line.Split(',');
           Array.Reverse(parts);
           list.Add(string.Join(" ", parts));
      }
}

list.Sort(new NameComparer());
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("outputfile.txt"))
{
    foreach(var line in list)
         writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with LINQ. Can you explain how to split the first and last name without LINQ?

Comment: I did not downvote this answer. I am unable to downvote or upvote anything as of yet because I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @user3426626 I updated my answer and I know you can't downvote.I didn't say it to you